# How to stop the gallery at the edge of the screen? (Android)

Tags: android, adapter, android-gallery

I am thinking about using Gallery.  If I'm scrolling to the right, I want the gallery to stop scrolling when the left most image comes to the edge of the left side of the display.  Ideally the left most image would be flush with the left side of the display but I'm not sure if it's possible with Gallery.

Currently when scrolling right, Gallery scrolls past the edge of the screen and leaves blank space to the left.

Sorry I don't have screen shots, but what I want to do is:

[image][image][image][image]...

and currently it is

[blank][image][image][image]...

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a horizontal listview instead.